# PHP - Parser file with a indenting

Tags: php, indentation

I have a file with the next structure:

```
    concept
        [at0000]    -- Blood Pressure
    language
        original_language = 
        translations = 
                author = 
                    ["organisation"] = 
                    ["email"] = 
                >
                accreditation = 
            >
        >
    description
        original_author = 
            ["organisation"] = 
            ["email"] = 
            ["date"] = 
        >
        details = 
                purpose =
```

I need to open and parse this file, but I must admit the indentations of each line, as the indentations represent hierarchical structures. Is there any way in PHP to go line by line analysis of the indentation, either the beginning, middle or end of the line?

Comment: What should the result of parsing that file be?

Comment: If the indentation is consistently used, it would certainly help lexing and parsing. Did you try anything yourself? Because presenting a file scheme and expecting to get a parser written is a bit unreasonable. Certainly the file didn't come into existence randomly, and there's a reference implementation or existing decoder. Otherwise transition to YAML, and don't reinvent the boat.

Comment: Is this a standard markup language of some kind? There may already be a parser for it.

Comment: @PatrickQ The result of the analysis is based on other algorithms, in my case, I just need to know for the indentation depth of the hierarchy.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice There is no parser, in fact, I'm creating a PHP class to use extends. This belongs to a markup standard for the exchange of electronic health information based on ISO 13606-2.

Comment: @Ale please select an answer

Comment: @PabloPazos  I have not finished my implementation, when it is done I will mark the answer

Comment: @Ale why marking an answer depends on finishing an implementation? there are valid answers, like there is no ADL parser in PHP and you need to use the XML version of archetypes...

Answer (score 1):

//rant on

It's simple: who provides such a crappy data structure to parse.
It's 2014. XML all over the place and lightweight JSON.
What do we get? Not even CSV :)

//rant off

Maybe a fixed column width parser would fit:
https://github.com/t-geindre/fixed-column-width-parser

Basically you get lines with `$lines  = file("file.txt");`

Then it's a matter of detecting the spaces or tabs in front of each line.

**Update**

Turns out this "data" has a structure.
The data-structure "Archetype Definition Language" (ADL) is described in ISO 13606-2.

- http://pangea.upv.es/en13606/index.php/resources/files/doc_download/2-en13606-part-2
- This document contains a grammar description in Chapter 8.
- You might use this grammer for parser construction.
- Parsing indentions is your smallest problem. Getting the data structure right, is the real task.
- Happy test writing - this will be a lot of work... be warned.

Let me also point to OpenEHR.

- OpenEHR uses Java and Eiffel as programming languages.
- The ADL parser is implemented in Java.
- You might find it at https://github.com/openEHR/java-libs/blob/master/adl-parser/src/main/javacc/adl.jj

This is the parser ADL v1.4 in Ruby:

- https://github.com/skoba/openehr-ruby/tree/master/lib/openehr/parser

This should get you pretty close to a solution. 
Hope this helps a bit..

Comment: This parser is to "read" a model of archetype for the electronic exchange of clinical information based on the standard ISO 13606-2. Initially created using this type of structure (version 1.4), version 1.5 is used XML, but as a rule of this standard is necessary to develop applications that support both versions. We are in the development of a class "open source" for we extend the use of the standard and is being done in PHP.

Comment: i've updated my answer with some more remarks about ADL and a pointer to the ADLParser of the OpenEHR project

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch Regarding the grammar, no problem since the concepts are clear. The solution in java has not been effective in the adoption of the standard, so the alternative for that implementation is much more effective to offer a class easier to use and to implement projects. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That syntax (ADL) has a canonical XML version that can be generated from many tools, CKM, Archetype Editor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ltrim` and `rtrim` functions.

For example using the following code:

```
$line = '    concept';

echo strlen(ltrim($line));
echo strlen($line);
```

you can calculate length of string with and without white-spaces at the beginning of the line.

However I don't know what you mean that you want to calculate indentations in the middle of the line. You should in that case go probably use `substr` function to go to the place when you expect indentation and then again use `ltrim` and strlen to calculate whitespaces at the beginning of substring.

You may also want to use [Mb string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) in case you have in your code non-ASCII characters.

For parsing lines you can simply use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

Answer (score 0):

ADL doesn't have a parser for PHP. But ADL can be transformed to XML using the CKM (http://ckm.openehr.org/ckm/) or the Archetype Editor (http://www.openehr.org/downloads/modellingtools).

You should use the XML in PHP.